# OCaml standard committee?

Tags: ocaml

I am doing a presentation on OCaml, I want to put if there is a standard comittee or not. I searched the internet far and wide and I couldn't get an answer for that, so I am asking for help here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OCaml does not follow any national or international standard. The language is whatever the Gallium (formerly Cristal) group at INRIA want it to be.

Comment: Thank you. I will mark this as an answer when the system lets me.

Answer (score 5):

The OCaml language does not have any standard, as there is only one implementation of it, namely OCaml itself. Some other experimental versions of OCaml exist (OCaml Java, one version that used to run on .NET) but as far as I know, none of them is considered serious enough (as of now) to be an alternative implementation. The Standard ML language has been standardized (as the name implies!), and implementations of it exist (SML/NJ, AliceML, MoscowML), but OCaml is not SML.

However, several industrial users of OCaml need agreement on the future directions of the language. A structure exists for that purpose, which is called the Caml Consortium http://caml.inria.fr/consortium/; future improvements on the language itself and its implementation may be discussed there. Technical discussions take place on a private list called caml-devel.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about an official standard like those produced by ISO, there's no indication of one. Computer languages are handled within ISO (and, to be honest, that's the most important standards body; all national bodies like ANSI and AS) tend to just feed into ISO) with technical committee 1, working group 22 (JTC1/SWG22).

A list of the standards issued for JTC1/SWG22 can be found [here](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_tc_browse.htm?commid=45202) and there's not a peep about OCaml.

Although there *are* some interesting snippets in there, such as Fortran being worked on as late as 2010, and Ruby in there but no Python.

That's not to say there may not be some standardisation effort outside of ISO or the national bodies, but it may be seen as less serious.

Comment: I'd be careful to equate "standardised" with "standardised by an official standards body". Such bodies are usually geared towards industrial and commercial technologies, and in some (e.g. Ecma) participation can cost significant fees. Hence, languages out of Academia, such as OCaml, are rarely carried there. Instead, informal groups or committees sometimes produce less official documents that are nevertheless acknowledged as standards in the community. Standard ML, Haskell'xy, or Scheme RxRS are examples for that. OCaml does not have one, though.

Comment: Interestingly, the Caml consortium charges 3000 euro for membership which seems to just give them a more liberal licence. Not sure how those fees rate against ISO since companies tend to be the main payers (and most of their costs would probably be participation rather than hard dollars), but it didn't seem to stop Ruby.

Comment: Well, the consortium is mainly a way for industry to contribute financially to the ongoing development and maintenance of the OCaml system. It's not really related to standardisation.